# Lambda expression to replace every items from the List<string> which match the string in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net

```
List
-----
A
B
A
D
F
```

Suppose I have a list as above.
I want to write lambda expression which replace every 'A' to 'C'
So the output would be as

```
List
----
C
B
C
D
F
```

As something will be done by for loop
but I want to write the lambda expression for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = list.Select(m => m == "A" ? "C" : m).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Replace method

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("A");
list.Add("B");
list.Add("C");
list.Add("D");
list.Add("A");
list.Add("B");

list = list.Select(x => x.Replace("A","C")).ToList();
```

Output is:
C
B
C
D
C
B